# Get Excel row index

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with currency pairs `USD/XYZ` or `XYZ/USD`, etc. in one column. I want to know the row number of the cell `USD/ABC` (suppose). Also, I want to know which rows have `USD` as the first three characters and which don't.

I want to do this using VBA.

Comment: it may be poorly worded, but it's a real question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the currency pairs are in column A, you can use a formula:

```
=MATCH("USD/EUR",A:A,0)
```

It will return the row where the currency is located (if there are duplicates, the row where it first appears is returned).

If you want to use VBA, you can read the data in an array and loop over the array (below an example looking for "EUR/USD" which you can adapt to your needs):

```
Sub test()

    Dim row As Long

    row = findCurrencyPair("EUR/USD")
    If row = 0 Then
        MsgBox "EUR/USD not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "EUR/USD found in row " & row
    End If

End Sub


Function findCurrencyPair(pair As String) As Long

    Dim data As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("SpotRates")
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).EntireRow.row

        data = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow) 'Replace A with the relevant column name
    End With

    If IsArray(data) = False Then Exit Function 'Empty sheet
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(i, 1) = pair Then
            findCurrencyPair = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    'if not found, returns 0

End Function
```

**EDIT**

Following @Readify comment, an even simpler solution would be (assuming the data only appears in one column):

```
Function findCurrencyPair(pair As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    findCurrencyPair = Sheets("SpotRates").Cells.Find(What:=pair).Row
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but can i use a function which I am then passing on to a procedure for further work on that? How will i make that one

Comment: I have edited the code to show an example of use.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..one more thing, if there are many sheets in that excel and i want to reference a particular sheet say SpotRates for that, where do i include that

Comment: `data = Sheets("SpotRates").UsedRange.Columns(1)`

Comment: Hi, one more thing columns(1) that you have written do i need to write the column name there?

Comment: no, its number - so for column A use `Columns(1)`, for column B, use `Columns(2)` etc.

Comment: can i instead somehow use the column name

Comment: I have amended the code.

Comment: +1 for seeing it to the end :)

Comment: @assylias, maybe I am missing something but why are you finding the last row and then looping through an array?  Why not just use the find function to find the currency pair?

Comment: @Reafidy I had started with a somewhat different code and after the various additions I agree that it would make more sense.

Comment: @user1323888, I believe all you need is:  `Function FindCurrencyPair(pair As String) As Long
     On Error Resume Next
     
     FindCurrencyPair = Sheets("SpotRates").Cells.Find(What:=pair).Row

End Function`

Comment: @Readfidy you should post it as an answer. Better than mine.

Comment: Thanks, but you did the hard work and your answer has already been accepted.  I just wanted to simplify it a bit for the benefit of others who may be reading in the future.

Comment: Thank you all..One more query, what if I need to search for a date through a column, that is, i pass a date as a parameter to the function and find the index where that date is there in the column?